# Add a comment on closing SASS/CSS brackets automatically in VScode

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, sass, vscode-snippets

I would like to add a comment on closing brackets, so when the code gets too nested the I can tell where each bracket belongs, something like this:

```
.parent{
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;

   .child{
       position: absolute;
       height: 50px;
       left: 25px;
       width: 50px;

       &:before{
           content: '';
           background: red;
           position: absolute;
           height: 50px;
           top: 25px;
           width: 50px;
       } // before
   } // .child
} // .parent
```

It would be awesome if this could be implemented as I type or on autosave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a snippet if you don't find an extension that will do it.  Put this in one of your snippets files:

```
"css: add comment": {
  "prefix": "|c",
  "body": [
    "${TM_CURRENT_LINE/(\\s*)&*:*(.*)?\\s*\\|c/{\n$1${1:-\t}\n$1} \\/* $2 *\\//}",
  ],
  "description": "add comment after closing bracket"
},
```

I am using `|c` as the prefix because it is the same as the emmet html comment filter.  I am not aware if you can get emmet to use a css comment filter.  But you can use whatever prefix you wish to trigger the snippet.  Here is a demo:

[image: demo of adding indented css elements with comments]

---

Here is a breakdown of the snippet body transform.

`${TM_CURRENT_LINE/(\\s*)&*:*(.*)?\\s*\\|c/` get the current line, capture group one will have the amount of indentation you need for the next indented child element.  Capture group 2 will have that current element's name - but any preceding `&:` will not be included in the name capture group.

`/{\n$1${1:-\t}\n$1} \\/* $2 *\\//` is the transformed text.

Add a newline, then add the proper amount of indentation (whitespace). If there was no previous indentation - like the first `.parent` entry - capture group 1 will be empty but we still need to add one tab in the middle of the next child element anyhow.

`${1:-\t}` is an else conditional that will add a tab when capture group 1 is empty as it will be when a parent element is started flush left.

Lastly, add the closing bracket and the name of the current element (capture group 2) surrounded by css comment indicators.

---

If you have an element that you don't want commented, just don't add the snippet prefix.

Comment: Awesome dude! This is perfect